# How to find what ports a program is trying to use (window)?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a problem with finding a port or ports that a specific program is trying to use.

A little about what I'm trying to do:

I have a DVR (digital video recorder), a couple IP cameras, a switch (hub) and a router.

For the DVR and cameras I use an internal IP (192.168.1.x), all are connected to a switch. The switch is connected to the router’s internal interface (192.168.1.1), and routers' external IP is let's say, 10.10.10.x.

I'm trying to connect to the DVR through the external IP. I made NAT rules, that I can connect using an internet browser, and 80 port, everything works, but when I try to use a program that is meant for this DVR, the program can't establish any connection to the DVR.

How can I find what kind of port or ports this program is trying to use when making connection to DVR, so that I can make necessary port forwarding?

I was trying with netstat, but it’s clear to me that Wireshark is better. 
But I need some help with how to use Wireshark. Do I connect the PC directly to the router, and then try to add the DVR to the program from another PC, while watching Wireshark?

Answer (score 2):

How about CurrPorts from http://www.nirsoft.net for Windows? Is that relevant to your situation?

> Description
>
> CurrPorts displays the list of all currently opened TCP/IP and UDP ports
> on your local computer. For each port in the list, information about the
> process that opened the port is also displayed, including the process
> name, full path of the process, ...

Download, unzip, run, no installation. Works for me to find what is using ports on my Windows machine.

Comment: NirSoft has a nice collection of utilities, I use them in combination with the SysInternals suite (I specially like SmartSniff).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SysInternals TPCView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) from Microsoft, it will show all the open ports with their associated programs and where they are connected to, also includes a command-line version (TCPVcon) if your prefer that way.

It doesn't need installation, but maybe you need to launch it as an Administrator to view some details about system processes.

(Also, the NirSoft utility suggested in another answer is a good option too)